# Fill java class members with c structure members

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a code something similar to this

```
struct time
{
    long milliscnds;
    int  secs;
}
```

In my java file , I had something like this

```
class jtime
{
    long millscnds;
    int  secs;
}
```

new jtime time = new jtime();

public int native getTimeFromC(object time);

in native class

```
getTimeFromc(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,jobject jtime)
 {
   struct time *mytime = getTime(); 

  now to fill the jtime with mytime
 }
```

Suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
void getTimeFromc(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject jtime)
{
    struct time *mytime = getTime(); 

    // now to fill the jtime with mytime
    jclass jtimeClazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(jtime); // Get the class for the jtime object
    // get the field IDs for the two instance fields
    jfieldID millscndsFieldId = (*env)->GetFieldID(jtimeClazz, "milliscnds", "J"); // 'J' is the JNI type signature for long
    jfieldID secsFieldId = (*env)->GetFieldID(jtimeClazz, "secs", "I"); // 'I' is the JNI type signature for int
    // set the fields
    (*env)->SetLongField(jtime, millscndsFieldId, (jlong)mytime.milliscnds);
    (*env)->SetIntField(jtime, secsFieldId, (jint)mytime.secs);
}
```

Ideally you should cache the values of `millscndsFieldId` and `secsFieldId` as they won't change during execution (and you could also cache `jtimeClazz` if you `NewGlobalRef` it).

All JNI functions are documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

Comment: Thank you very much , i have a doubt , can i free the struct after setting the java members ...?

Comment: Yep, there is no shared memory here - you're copying the values

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your Java class and the required JNI code.

Currently, your native method has some issues:

```
public int native getTimeFromC(object time);
```

1. Parameter is `Object` but should be `jtime`.
2. Return value doesn't seem to have a purpose.
3. Since the method completely initializes a `jtime` object, why not create and return a `jtime` object?

This class definition has a factory method to create the object and a constructor that moves some the initialization work over from the JNI side.

```
public class jtime {

    long millscnds;
    int  secs;

    public jtime(long millscnds, int secs) {
        this.millscnds = millscnds;
        this.secs = secs;
    }

    public native static jtime FromC();
}
```

The factory method can be implemented like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_jtime_FromC
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz)
{
    struct time *mytime = getTime();

    jmethodID ctor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "<init>", "(JI)V");
    jobject obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, clazz, ctor, mytime->milliscnds, mytime->secs);

    return obj;
}
```

**Tip:** The `javap` tool is like `javah` but shows the signatures of non-native methods. Using `javap -s jtime`, you can see the signature of the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i am intentionally returning int which sends me the result which i need in future